# Outlook resizes images when embedded from attachment vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've got some code that attach and hide images to an outlook mail so they can be embedded, and also inserts the user signature on the end.

Got 2 problems:

- Outlook resizes the image if it's too large so its view is awfull.

If I manually correct this by setting the Width and Height at 100% scale unlocking the aspect ratio the image shows ok but its cut by the signature. Correcting this by wrapping the image in front  of the text leaves the signature behind the image so it doesn't show.

Is there any way to correct this please?

Here is my code(which i've been taking from other posts):

```
Sub Mail()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim myFileList(1) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Call CrearImagen

myFileList(0) = wb.Path & "\ImagenesMail\Imagen0.jpg"
myFileList(1) = wb.Path & "\ImagenesMail\Imagen1.jpg"

strbody = "Hola"

On Error Resume Next


With OutMail
    .display
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Como quedaría el mail"
    For i = 0 To UBound(myFileList)
        .Attachments.Add myFileList(i)
    Next i

    'width=width height=heigth
    'width=width height=heigth
    .HTMLBody = "<br>" & strbody & "<br><br>" _
        & "<img src='cid:Imagen0.jpg'><br><br>" _
        & "<img src='cid:Imagen1.jpg'><br><br>" _
        & "<br>Prueba<br>prueba</font></span>" & .HTMLBody
    .display
End With

On Error GoTo 0
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is how it looks by default:

[Default paste](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F32NC.png)

This is how it looks after the resize 100% scale on both Height and Width:

[After Resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDZUd.jpg)

As you can see, it shows as i would like, but not the whole image. If i wrap the image in front of the text then i've got the desired mail, but then the signature goes hidden behind the image.

I supose the image resize comes from the code I have commented, it uses numbers, not % scale.

PS: sorry for my bad english, not english speaker.

Comment: You could try something like `<img style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"
src="images/img.jpg" width="1200" height="1500">` instead? I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: But why they "1200" and "1500" not all my images are that large :/

Comment: It's just an example to see if it works for you. You could use `width"500px"` and `height="400px"` or `width"50%"` and `height="50%"`

Comment: It appears to work with `& "<img src='cid:img.jpg' style='margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;' src='images/img.jpg' width='10%' height='10%'><br><br>"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just tried, nothing changes, sure i don't know how to work on the HTMLBody, but the doubles quotes are messing with the code, so I left one on the beginning and one on the end of the code. Yet no changes :( about the aspect lock ratio `code`"<img style='margin:0' border:'0' padding:'0' display:'block' src='cid:Imagen1.jpg' width=856 height=2001>"`code`

Comment: Tried ur new code Cody G. i don't get why are you using src twice? src= cid... and src = images/img.jpg. Got it working, but still does the scale... leaving Height with 29% and width with 91% even though i used a 100% 100%: `<img src='cid:Imagen1.jpg' style='margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;' src='images/Imagen1.jpg' width='100%' height='100%'><br><br>`

Comment: That was an accident, shouldn't have both --- Like I said, I don't know too much about the HTML of emails but you can use HTML/CSS styles to help style them, just trying to point you in a direction. I don't know how outlook vs gmail vs any other web client renders this html so you're going to have to do a lot of 'testing' to get it the way you want...

Comment: @Cody G. what you've given to me is good, still need 2 things: unlock the aspect ratio and wrap the image in front of the text. Browsing i've found a code on html that does the unlock thing `aspectratio='f'` brought it back to my code but still won't work...  `<img src='cid:Imagen1.jpg' aspectratio='f'  width='100%' height='100%'><br><br>`

Comment: Whoops, only use width or height if you want to keep aspect ratio??

Answer (score 0):

Try This =>

```
<img src='cid:Imagen0.jpg' width=1150><br><br>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).